# array of struct read from file in C

Tags: c, array

I want to read csv file in to array of structs with NULL ending.

test.txt:

```
11,345,1,k
12,34.23,3,v
13,13.4,5,x
14,15.7,6,c
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct csv_line {
  int value1;
  float value3;
  int value2;
  char char1;
};

struct csv_line *line_pointer = NULL;

int main(void) {
    FILE *csvFile = NULL;
    csvFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (csvFile == NULL)
      exit(1);

    size_t i = 0;
    while (1) {
    line_pointer = (struct csv_line *)realloc(line_pointer, sizeof(struct csv_line) * (i + 1));
    if (fscanf(csvFile, "%d,%f,%d,%c",
            &(line_pointer + i)->value1,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value3,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value2,
            &(line_pointer + i)->char1) != EOF) {
      i++;
    } else{
        (line_pointer + i)->value1 = 0;
        (line_pointer + i)->value3 = 0.0;
        (line_pointer + i)->value2 = 0;
        (line_pointer + i)->char1 = '\0';
        break;
     }
    }
    fclose(csvFile);
    int k = 0;
    while('\0' != (line_pointer + k)->char1) {
        printf("%d, %.2f, %d, %c",
                (line_pointer + k)->value1,
                (line_pointer + k)->value3,
                (line_pointer + k)->value2,
                (line_pointer + k)->char1);
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }

    free(line_pointer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Questons:

1. Is it possible to move fscanf condition inside while-loop condition instead of endless (1) ?
2. How to set "end" of array with single NULL like "line_pointer[i] = NULL" in else statement?

Answer (score 4):

user3629249's answer is good. The only thing I have to add:

```
struct csv_line *line_pointer = NULL;

// ...

&(line_pointer + i)->value1
```

is awkward. Why go through the pointer addition acrobatics? Why not just

```
&line_pointer[i].value1
```

Comment: I agree with using an 'index' rather than pointer addition.  However, I did not want to confuse the OP

Answer (score 1):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. takes into account the comments to the OPs question
4. properly checks for errors when calling `malloc()` and `realloc()` and `fopen()` and `fscanf()`
5. the `while()` loop uses the function: `fscanf()` rather than a '1' as the loop condition
6. uses the value in `i` to determine when the end of the data is reached
7. sets the last instance of the struct to NULL per the OPs request
8. per Reinderien's answer and for ease of readability, statements like `&(line_pointer + i)->value1` (which uses pointer addition) could be replaced with: `&(line_pointer[i].value1` (which uses indexing)

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct csv_line {
  int value1;
  float value3;
  int value2;
  char char1;
};

struct csv_line *line_pointer = NULL;

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *csvFile = NULL;
    csvFile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (csvFile == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t i = 1;
    line_pointer = malloc( sizeof(struct csv_line) * i );
    if( ! line_pointer )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose( csvFile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while ( (fscanf(csvFile, "%d,%f,%d,%c",
                &(line_pointer + i)->value1,
                &(line_pointer + i)->value3,
                &(line_pointer + i)->value2,
                &(line_pointer + i)->char1) ) == 4 )
    {
        i++;
        struct csv_line *temp = realloc(line_pointer, sizeof(struct csv_line) * i );
        if( ! temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            free( line_pointer );
            fclose( csvFile );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose(csvFile);

    // per the request that the last entry contains NULL
    memset( &line_pointer[i], 0, sizeof( struct csv_line ) );

    for( size_t k=0; k < (i-1); k++ ) 
    {
        printf("%d, %.2f, %d, %c",
                (line_pointer + k)->value1,
                (line_pointer + k)->value3,
                (line_pointer + k)->value2,
                (line_pointer + k)->char1);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(line_pointer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

you could try this loop instead:

```
size_t i = 0;

do
{
    i++;
    struct csv_line *temp = realloc(line_pointer, sizeof(struct csv_line) * i );
    if( ! temp )
    {
        perror( "realloc failed" );
        free( line_pointer );
        fclose( csvFile );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} while ( (fscanf(csvFile, "%d,%f,%d,%c",
            &(line_pointer + i)->value1,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value3,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value2,
            &(line_pointer + i)->char1) ) == 4 );
```

so there is only one place allocating memory

Comment: _Why_ does this code allocate an extra instance? By just saying _what_ you changed but not _why_, your answer had almost no value since it doesn't explain best practices. Plus, you forgot to format the code properly.

Comment: Win, mingw debugger fails here: struct csv_line *temp = realloc(line_pointer, sizeof(struct csv_line) * i );

Comment: I was much more interested in showing the OP how to use the call to `fscanf()` for the control of the `while()` loop as that is what the OP ask about.  I also demonstrated how to call `realloc()` so as to avoid a memory leak.  I also demonstrated how to handle an error.

Comment: @GarfieldCat,  Please post the error message you are getting on the statement that performs the `realloc()`

Comment: @RolandIllig,  and what would be 'best practices' for the current scenario?

Comment: @RolandIllig, Since the OP ask for the last instance to be filled with NULL,  I have added a call to `memset()` to handle that request.

Comment: Thread #1 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGTRAP:Trace/breakpoint trap)
ntdll!EtwEventProviderEnabled() at 0x77269372 ntdll!RtlFindClearBits() at 0x772795f1

Comment: @GarfieldCat,  As far as I can tell, the error message you provided has nothing to do with a call to `realloc()`

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions in reverse order:

> How to set "end" of array with single `NULL` like `line_pointer[i] = NULL` in `else` statement?

You can (with `memset`, as shown in other answers), but it's not guaranteed by the C standard that the `float` value will be set to zero. I would instead suggest to set every value in the structure to zero as you are already doing.

> Is it possible to move `fscanf` condition inside `while`-loop condition instead of endless `(1)`?

You may be able to do this, but I don't recommend it. This would make your code harder to read and comprehend.

Some other issues:

### Check the return value of the *`alloc` family of functions

Right here, a crash could happen if you're out of memory:

```
line_pointer = (struct csv_line *)realloc(line_pointer, sizeof(struct csv_line) * (i + 1));
```

You should add a check just like you do with `csvFile`:

```
if(!line_pointer)
    exit(1);
```

Of course, a better error message could be formulated with `perror`:

```
if(!line_pointer)
{
    perror("realloc(line_pointer)");
    exit(1);
}
```

`perror` will work when `fopen` fails as well.

### Check the return value of `fscanf` correctly

Instead of checking if you've reached the end-of-file,
check whether you didn't read as many variables as expected.
This provides a minimal aspect of data validation:

```
    if (fscanf(csvFile, "%d,%f,%d,%c",
            &(line_pointer + i)->value1,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value3,
            &(line_pointer + i)->value2,
            &(line_pointer + i)->char1) != 4)
```

### Use `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of `1`

As you're using `EXIT_SUCCESS` to show success, you should go for consistency (and portability) by using `EXIT_FAILURE` in place of `1` in `exit`.

### Use `return` instead of `exit`

In addition to the above, in `main` you can forego using `exit` and instead use `return`. There's really no need to use `exit` in a program under normal circumstances, anyway.

### Don't cast the return value of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`

The return value of `realloc` can be implicitly converted to any object pointer. It's not necessary to cast it, and in my opinion, avoiding unnecessary casts is a good thing.

### Use array and structure access operators instead of pointer arithmetic

To me, this looks odd:

```
(struct_pointer + ctr)->member
```

Instead, you can use array access and the `.` operator:

```
struct_pointer[ctr].member
```

This applies equivalently to when you're taking the address of `member`.

### Use consistent indentation

In some places, you use two spaces, while in others you use one and four. I suggest sticking to one indentation style, whatever it is. Personally, I use four or a tab, but you can use whatever you want if it's consistent. See the [Linux Kernel Coding Style Guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html) for more information.

### Yoda conditions

Backwards, your conditions are. This is hard to read and provides little to no benefit, considering that compilers now warn about typos that Yoda conditions originally solved:

```
while('\0' != (line_pointer + k)->char1)
```

Instead, just use `!=` the "normal" way:

```
while((line_pointer + k)->char1 != '\0')
```